# If 'beautiful soup' is searched, how can the value be represented as "" when it does not exist?

Tags: python

```
   for ticker in tickers:
        ticker_name = str(ticker.get_text())
        url_yahoo_finance = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{}/financials?p={}'.format(ticker_name,ticker_name)
        yahoo_finance_res = requests.get(url_yahoo_finance,headers=headers)
        yahoo_finance_soup = BeautifulSoup(yahoo_finance_res.content,'lxml')
        company_name = yahoo_finance_soup.select_one('div.D\(ib\) > h1').get_text()
        print(company_name)
        net_income = yahoo_finance_soup.select_one('div.D\(tbrg\) > div:nth-child(10) > div.D\(tbr\).fi-row.Bgc\(\$hoverBgColor\)\:h > div:nth-child(2) > span')

    **if type(net_income) == '<class \'NoneType\'>':
        print('none')
        continue
    else:
        print(net_income.get_text())**
```

The third value does not exist. So if it's `NoneType`, I tried to ignore it and proceed with the code, but the third value does not apply to `type(net_income) == '<class \'NoneType\`. I wonder how to solve it.

If `beautiful soup` is searched, how can the value be represented as "" when it does not exist?

Comment: Have you tried `if net_income is None` or `if type(net_income) == type(None)`? The `type()` function doesn't return a string, it returns a class.

Comment: You could however use `if str(type(net_income)) == '<class \'NoneType\'>'` which would still work.